# Check column names and column types in Great Expectations

Tags: python, great-expectations

Currently, I am validating the table schema with `expect_table_columns_to_match_set` by feeding in a list of columns. However, I want to validate the schema associated with each column such as `string`. The only available Great Expectations rule `expect_column_values_to_be_of_type` has to be written for each column name and also creates redundancy by repeating the column names.

Is there any rule that I am missing that I can validate both the name and the schema at the same time?

For exmaple, given column `a: string, b: int, c: boolean`, I want to pass that whole info into one function instead of having to break it into `[a,b,c]` and validating `[a],` string` separately for each column.

Ideally, it will be something like `expect_column_schmea([(column_name_a, column_type_a), (column_name_b, column_type_b)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `expect_column_values_to_match_json_schema` (or regex / pattern - depending on what you are more comfortable with). [Here](https://docs.greatexpectations.io/docs/reference/expectations/implemented_expectations/) is the list of expectations that are possible to use.

With [`expect_column_values_to_match_json_schema`](https://legacy.docs.greatexpectations.io/en/latest/autoapi/great_expectations/expectations/core/expect_column_values_to_match_json_schema/index.html) you can define your schema in a json format:

```
schema = {
    "column_name_a": {"type": "string"},
    "column_name_b": {"type": "integer"},
    "column_name_c": {"type": "boolean"},
}
```

Create a new `ExpectColumnValuesToMatchSchema` instance (import for that was `from great_expectations.expectations.core.expect_column_values_to_match_schema import ( ExpectColumnValuesToMatchSchema, )`):

`expectation = ExpectColumnValuesToMatchSchema(schema=schema)`

And finally validate it to get your results: `result = expectation.validate(dataset)!

You will get a [`ExpectationSuiteValidationResult`](https://docs.greatexpectations.io/docs/terms/validation_result/) as a return and can accordingly check whether the columns you provided match / do not match the schema!